# R Markdown not working with Tensorflow code

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, r-markdown

I successfully built a model in R Script using Tensorflow and Keras. When I copy that same code into a R Markdown file and try to knit to make a report, I receive this error. What can I do to remedy this?

```
"2022-09-29 19:21:42.705317: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-09-29 19:21:42.705857: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Quitting from lines 11-67 (SentimentAnalysisMarkdownRAW.Rmd) 
Error: 

Execution halted"
```

Comment: One limitation of reticulate (presently) is that R error messages are truncated when they are signaled from an R function that was called by a Python function. It looks like that's going on here, because your Error message is truncated.  You should try to debug your code first just in R, then once you're sure it works, run it in Rmarkdown.

Comment: Thanks @t-kalinowski - that's what puzzles me. My code works as expected in R, but running the exact same code in Markdown throws the execution halted error.